# How to insert a string like "Pyrénées, France'" in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i insert string "Pyrénées, France'" in mysql database. How can i remove special characters form that string using php?

Comment: Why would you remove those characters in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert it and make sure that the charset of your database supports your special characters. It might be best to switch the charset of your database to UTF-8.

Comment: i have set Charset in db is utf8_general_ci 
But not working for me any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the string to ASCII. By using the `TRANSLIT` and `IGNORE` flags it will try to substitute characters not supported in the target charset and strip any remaining invalid characters.

However, better configure your database to accept UTF8 strings so you can simply store the data without modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert it like that. If your encoding is correct, you will have no problems at all.
You should not remove any 'special characters' here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a proper charset for your database or table (UTF-8, `utf8_general_ci`), you won't have to remove special characters.

<s>Alternatively you could use `htmlspecialchars()` to convert possibly 'malicious' characters into HTML-Entities.</s>

If you remove special characters, I see the problem that words could end up not making proper sense anymore.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is nothing you should use on input but on output, i.e. when displaying the data.

Comment: @ThiefMaster true, but OP asked for a solution to store the data without special characters. This would be a possible way to do it.

Comment: No, it would not touch accents etc at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove any special characters you can use this function:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]/s', '', $text);
```

It will replace any non-special chars with empty char.

Comment: That will turn some proper words into nonsense.

Comment: -1 It's not really recommended to lose informations before an insert into a database.